# Сравнение результатов запроса

Tags: java, mysql

Пишу на `java` программу, которая будет проверять правильность введенного `sql` запроса на выборку (использую `MySQL`), имеется правильный ответ в отдельной таблице, погуглил узнал что люди решавшие эту проблему с помощью `java` писали что-то для `resultset` (не имею представления как это реализовать и примеров не нашел) а те кто решали с помощью mysql извращались соединениями подзапросами, второй вариант не подходить так как изначально я не знаю имена столбцов (могу быть и не прав так как не на ты с `MySQL`), в общем помогите в написании чего-то для `resultset`.

---

**up**
Думаю кому-то будет интерес мой опыт:
так как в таблице имелись правильные ответы некий под псевдонимом **sonniy** предложить сравнивать ответы, но его ответ встретил шквал критики, имея готовый ответ я все же решил поискать еще решения этой проблемы, узнал что это все в оракле реализовывается в пару строк, полез на офф сайт и увидев размер субд передумал, позже вернулся к своему первому варианту к resultset, покопавшись нашел что искал, итог я сделал две проверки первая на результат а вторая это вариант предложенный **sonniy** я ее использовал для проверки лишних операторов (проверка как бы на оптимальность запроса).

```
while (resultSet.next()){
    for (int i = 1; i <= resultSet.getMetaData().getColumnCount(); i++){
        System.out.println(resultSet.getObject(i));
    }
```

Comment: google (java + mysql + resultset) => http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Database-SQL-JDBC/DemoResultSetforMySQL.htm

Comment: ИМХО методика от конкретной БД принципиально не отличается...

Либо синтасический анализ, либо попробовать выполныть и сказать, была ли ошибка.

Comment: [ResultSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html) это примерно то же самое что и [курсор](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cursors.html) в хранимках MySQL

Comment: Barmaley скажите нормально будет если выполнить оба запроса (сохранить результаты в разных resultset) и перебирать каждую строку и сравнивать? 
SilverIce первый не подходить, вопрос насчет второго варианта а если запрос правильно (синтаксический) написан а результат не тот тогда ее как определить?

Comment: Это учебное задание, интерфейс к БД или вы преподавателю решили подогнать программу для тестирования студентов? :)
У Вас будут только селекты и только их требуется проверять?

> имеется правильный ответ в отдельной
> таблице

 Что там ? Весь запрос, или какие то части ?

> если запрос правильно (синтаксический)
> написан а результат не тот

 Это как ?

Comment: вы угадали (решил подогнать), будут только селекты (там простые сложные), имеется весь правильный ответ, легче с ResultSet работать или анализировать синтаксис?

Comment: Не вижу смысла анализировать синтаксис запроса. Просто попробуйте его выполнить, в случае неверного синтаксиса вылетит `Exception`.

Comment: ну я эту проверку уже сделал я сейчас на стадии сравнения результатов.

Comment: Вам в первом ответе дали ссылку как делать выборку результатов на Java. Там даже есть ResultSet, о котором вы слышали.

Answer (score 3):

Ну раз имеется весь правильный ответ, то тут не синтаксис проверять нужно :)

Давайте пойдем постепенно(учитывая что уже создали коннект и стайтмен):

```
String query_set = "SELECT * FROM table"; // считанный введенный кем то запрос
ResultSet rs = state.executeQuery(query_set);
```

query_set - это строка, собственно ее и нужно сравнивать с тем что есть у Вас в таблице

```
String query_set = "SELECT * FROM table";
// тут делаем вставку
String right_answer;
try {
 ResultSet rs = state.executeQuery("Select count(*) from table_answer where answer='"+query_set+"'"); // ищем количество совпадений в БД 
     if (rs.next()) {
        right_answer = rs.getString(1); // получаем ответ
     }
     rs.close(); // закрываем резуль сет
} catch (SQLException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
}
if(Integer.parseInt(right_answer) > 0){ // если совпадения были то выполняем "настоящий" запрос
    ResultSet rs_true = state.executeQuery(query_set); // тут следует поменять имя rs. на другое так как rs мы уже закрыли
    // обрабатываете результат и выводите
} else { // в противном случае выводите сообщение о неправильном запросе
    String msg = "запрос составлен не верно";
    System.out.println(msg);
}
```

**UPD**

```
    String str = "Select              * FROM   alsd     ";
    String[] arr = str.split(" ");
    String str2 = "";
    for (String x:arr){
        if(x.length()>0){
            str2+=x+" ";
        }
    }
            System.out.println(str);
    System.out.println(str2);
```

такую же штуку можно сделать и с энтерами, а еще можно все привести к ловер кейсу или аперкейсу ...

Comment: я насчет такого решения думал, решил что не разумно ее использовать, так как sql может принять такой ответ за правильный select * from table (а правильный ответ у нас SELECT * FROM table), а вот лишние пробелы и ентры все испортят (( и sql запрос не будет верным ((

Comment: обновил ответ

Comment: str, str2,  snake_case... за что??

Comment: @rasmisha мне вот любопытно, а как Вы хотели ?

Comment: @sonniy http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconv-138413.html

и по поводу вашего UPD, а чем replaceAll не угодил?

Comment: @sonniy скажите, а какой запрос будет правильным для таблицы users (id, login):

1. ``select * from users``
2. ``select id, login from users``
3. ``select login, id from users``
4. ``select * from (select * from users where 1=1) users``

Они все возвращают одни и те же данные, так какой правильный?

hint: результат не всегда однозначно определяется текстом запроса.

Comment: @Yura Ivanov параноя такая параноя... читайте условия задачи, если бы требовалось действительно проверять синтаксис ответ был бы другой

@rasmisha я с вами согласен, но очень плохо знаю регекспы, вот и все :D

Comment: @sonniy вы только на работе пожалуйста пишите в сamelCase, если работаете на джава :) прошу от лица ваших коллег

Comment: @sonniy, ваше решение в лоб не пропустит любой правильный ответ отличный от "мнения учитиля". Количество аппеляций будет равно общему количеству запросов. Польза от такой программы нулевая. Особенно доставляет ваш upd, насмешили, да.

Comment: @Yura Ivanov человеку требуется сравнивать значения с УЖЕ ЗАВЕДОМО ВНЕСЕННЫМИ в БД, и еще раз повторюсь, если бы задача была другая то и ответ был бы другой. Напишите свой и я его оценю по достоинству.

Comment: @sonniy ваш ответ принят, не вижу смысла переубеждать ТС в том, что выбранный им путь, который вы ему подсказали, неверен в корне. Очевидно к этому нужно прийти самостоятельно. Вы решили задачу поиска строк в таблице, да еще так многословно. То, что в бд внесены правильные запросы идентифицирует лишь выборку - поля, количество строк, возможно скорость выполнения запроса. А то, что вы предлагаете - игра угадайка с какой ноги встал учитель. Про более сложные запросы даже для таблиц больше одной вообще говорить нечего, учитывая предположение, что вводимые запросы отличаться могут только пробелам

Comment: нашел то что мне нужно сравнение результатов, ваше обалденный способ (в пару строк) это просто поменять бд на оракл и там использовать минус ))